# Android is it possible to check user allow or not allow location permission

Tags: android, location, android-location

I am working on Location Services, I need to know how can check user click button Allow or Reject Permission Dialog? or Location Services are on or off for the app?

[image]

Comment: Read this first: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I think its just use in 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can easily be done. Please see the [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
The code below, copied form the docs, shows how to check if user approves or cancels a permission request:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
>             // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0
>                 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I think its just use in 6.0.